# Knowledge Article Version not being retrieved through an SOQL on Site

Tags: soql, knowledge

I am trying to query the Knowledge Article Version object based on a list of Knowledge Article IDs that I have.
The query seems to be working fine if I run it on the org or in the code, however when the same soql is being executed through a controller hosted on the site, it does not return anything.

I defined the class as having without sharing, but still that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you check the site permissions for the component's are controller,Object's and FLS (Field Level Security)?